# Mac OS SwiftUI inline text editing completions

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-texteditor

Xcode on OS X has really nice **inline** automatic completions / suggestions while editing text with embedded documentation and such. How would I even start to achieve something like this using SwiftUI's `TextEditor`?

[image: Xcode's nice inline text completions]

My question here isn't about building up the data to offer for suggestions. It's about how to have `TextEditor` interact with my code so I can provide an inline overlay populated with suggestions?

Possibly `TextEditor` just doesn't do this, which would be a perfectly good answer if that's the case! If it is possible, a great answer might give a brief example of how to hook a `TextEditor` with in inline overlay of some kind and some pointers to relevant bits of the API to achieve this.

If this isn't possible in SwiftUI, then how to do it with UIKit would also be very interesting to know.

Thanks.

Comment: Not possible with TextEditor.

Comment: `TextEditor` gives you no access to layout information. If you want to do this sort of thing, you're going to need to drop down to `UITextView` or `NSTextView` to get access to the `textLayoutManager` just to know where to put the popup.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the [`STTextView` project](https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/STTextView), which is an open-source implementation of a text editor using TextKit2 and, at 1 minute into its demo video, shows Xcode-style popup completion.

Comment: @robmayoff super, thank you 

Answer (score 1):

you could try this (very rough) approach of using `.onChange(...)` for interaction,
and a `.popover(...)` (or your own popup view) to display your suggestions.

The example code shows a popup when you type `x` in the `TextEditor`, then click on an item to select it.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var txt = ""
    @State var showme = false
    
    @FocusState var isFocused: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // tappable clear background to dismiss the keyboard and popup
            Color.white.opacity(0.001).ignoresSafeArea(.all)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showme = false
                    isFocused = false
                }
            
            TextEditor(text: $txt).border(.red)
                .focused($isFocused)
                .onChange(of: txt) {
                    // some logic here
                    if txt.last == "x" {
                        showme = true
                    }
                }.frame(height: 88)
            
            // in MacCatalyst/macOS
            // .popover(isPresented: $showme) {
            //    Popup(showme: $showme, txt: $txt)
            // }
            
            if showme {
                Popup(showme: $showme, txt: $txt)
            }
            
        }
    }
}

struct Popup: View {
    @Binding var showme: Bool
    @Binding var txt: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("item-1") { txt = "item-1"; showme = false}
            Button("item-2") { txt = "item-2"; showme = false}
        }
        .frame(width: 77, height: 100)
        .padding(10)
        .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
        .background(Color.yellow)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! … Am I right that where the Popup shows isn't specifically related to where the cursor currently is in the editor? If that's the case, this isn't quite what I'm hoping for, but it is still a helpful answer so I'm voting it up. Thanks.

Comment: thanks. Correct, but you can adjust the `Popup` position with eg:
 `.position(x: ..., y: ...)` or `.offset(x: ..., y: ...)`.
 However, the `STTextView` project seems to be very slick.

Comment:  If I used the offset, is there a way for TextView to tell me where I should position the popup?

Comment: Probably, look into `GeometryReader` with .global or .local frame of references
 to position the `Popup` exactly where you want it to display.
 See also: https://swiftui-lab.com/geometryreader-to-the-rescue/  and  
 https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/understanding-frames-and-coordinates-inside-geometryreader